# Retrieve CVSampleBuffer from AVCapturePhoto obtained through AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate

Tags: ios, avfoundation

As in the title, I'm trying to retrieve the CVPixelBuffer for a captured photo from output of the method:

`AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate.photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)`

The `photo` parameter's `pixelBuffer` is `nil` in the delegate method call and I'd like to use it for some low level image manipulation.

I've been mostly following the sample code which can be found at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

and the AVFoundation documentation.

Since the AVFoundation session configuration is kinda lengthy and might provide some answers, I'll just paste the whole object that handles it, which should contain all of the related code:

```
protocol CameraServiceDelegate: class {
    func cameraServiceDidCapturePhoto(withBuffer buffer: CVPixelBuffer)
    func cameraServiceEncounteredError(_ error: Error?)
}

final class CameraService: NSObject {

    struct BufferRetrievalFailure: Error {}

    weak var delegate: CameraServiceDelegate?

    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private var discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
        deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera],
        mediaType: .video,
        position: .back
    )
    private var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    private let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "av-capture-session.serial.queue")

    private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? {
        return .default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            ?? .default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            ?? .default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
    }

    func setup(with layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        layer.session = session

        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            requestVideoAuthorization()
        default:
            assertionFailure("Just enable video, this is not a real app.")
        }

        sessionQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.setupAVSession(with: layer)
        }
    }

    func resume() {
        sessionQueue.async { [weak session] in
            session?.startRunning()
        }
    }

    func suspend() {
        sessionQueue.async { [weak session] in
            session?.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func capturePhoto() {
        sessionQueue.async { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            strongSelf.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: strongSelf.capturePhotoSettings(), delegate: strongSelf)
        }
    }

    private func requestVideoAuthorization() {
        sessionQueue.suspend()

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { [weak sessionQueue] isAuthorized in
            guard isAuthorized else {
                assertionFailure("Just enable video, this is not a real app.")
                return
            }

            sessionQueue?.resume()
        }
    }

    private func setupAVSession(with layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        session.beginConfiguration()

        session.sessionPreset = .photo

        setupVideoInput()
        setupVideoPreviewViewLayer(with: layer)
        setupPhotoOutput()

        session.commitConfiguration()
    }

    private func setupVideoInput() {
        guard let videoDevice = captureDevice,
              let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
              session.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
            fatalError("Could not retrieve suitable capture device or configure video device input.")
        }

        self.deviceInput = deviceInput
        session.addInput(deviceInput)
    }

    private func setupVideoPreviewViewLayer(with layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let statusBarOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

            layer.connection?.videoOrientation =
                statusBarOrientation != .unknown
                    ? AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: statusBarOrientation.rawValue)!
                    : .portrait
        }
    }

    private func setupPhotoOutput() {
        guard session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) else {
            fatalError("Could not configure photo output.")
        }

        session.addOutput(photoOutput)

        photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = false
        photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
    }

    private func capturePhotoSettings() -> AVCapturePhotoSettings {
        let settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings

        if photoOutput.availablePhotoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc) {
            settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
        } else {
            settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        }

        settings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        settings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled

        return settings
    }
}

extension CameraService: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            delegate?.cameraServiceEncounteredError(error)
            return
        }

        guard let buffer = photo.pixelBuffer else {
            delegate?.cameraServiceEncounteredError(BufferRetrievalFailure())
            return
        }

        delegate?.cameraServiceDidCapturePhoto(withBuffer: buffer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a code sample for you because I'm working in Xamarin, but you need to set the [`previewPhotoFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1648696-previewphotoformat?language=objc) on the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` object used when creating the capture. An example I [found online](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-avcapturephotooutputs-best-photo-features/):

```
var settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
let previewFormat = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
    kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: self.capturedButton.frame.width,
    kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: self.capturedButton.frame.height
] as [String : Any]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
```

Personally I inspect the [`availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1778629-availablepreviewphotopixelformat?language=objc) to see if the format that I require for my analysis ([`kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers/kcvpixelformattype_32bgra?language=objc)) is even in there. I haven't encountered a device without it so far.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like this might be the solution.